# Run Multiple .exe Files from a Batch File Simultaneously and Silently

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10, exe

I am on windows 10 and i need to run multiple executable files from a batch file silently, without waiting for them to finish. at the moment i have:

```
@echo off
start "" "%~dp0executable.exe" /q
start "" "%~dp0executable2.exe" /q
```

but this still opens multiple console windows.
any workarounds that achieve the same results are welcome.

Comment: `start "" /B ...`?

Comment: worked a treat, can't believe i didn't find this before, do you want to post this as an answer so we can close the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your executables seem to be console applications, otherwise no console window would appear.

Anyway, the [`start` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) features an option `/B`; here is an excerpt of the output of `start /?`:

> ```cmd
>     B           Start application without creating a new window. The
>                 application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
>                 enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
>                 the application.
> ```

By `^C` and `^Break`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pause/Break</kbd> is meant, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a third .exe that needs to wait after the first two started simultaneously you can also use the start /w argument for the second one and call the third like so:

```
@echo off
start /B "%~dp0executable.exe"
start /W "%~dp0executable2.exe"
call "%~dp0executable3.exe"
```